# Reformat Excel data-frame

Tags: python, pandas

I managed to get my python script working to scrape data from a website using Playwright.
The website data is in a format not usable to us at the moment. Here is an example of the initial extract:

| Name | Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 | Group 4 | Group 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe Black | A |  |  | U |  |
| Joe Blue |  | A | A |  |  |
| Joe Green | U |  |  |  | A |
| Joe Red |  | A |  | U |  |

The A in the table above means the users are admins of the group. I need to get the data above into a table that has the groups in the 1st row and in the 2nd row if they are admins of the group have their names listed. So basically I need to get it to this:

| Groups | Admins |
| --- | --- |
| Group 1 | Joe Blue,Joe Red |
| Group 2 | Joe Red |
| Group 3 | Joe Blue |
| Group 4 | Joe Blue |
| Group 5 | Joe Green |

I am trying to use Pandas but completely lost on how to get the format correct. Just need some advice or a reference to a similar problem I can work off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape with [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), then [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
out = (df.melt('Name', var_name='Group').dropna(subset='value')
         .groupby('Group')['Name'].agg(', '.join).reset_index(name='Admins')
       )
```

Variant with a [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
(df.set_index('Name').rename_axis(index='Admins', columns='Group')
   .stack().reset_index()
   .groupby('Group', as_index=False)['Admins'].agg(', '.join)
)
```

Output:

```
     Group             Admins
0  Group 1          Joe Black
1  Group 2  Joe Blue, Joe Red
2  Group 3           Joe Blue
3  Group 5          Joe Green
```

Comment: very kind of you @Dinerz, happy coding ;)

Comment: Thanks! Works well so far but it also selecting non admins, just need to ignore rows with U

Comment: @Dinerz I hadn't seen the Us in the original question. Then replace `.dropna(subset='value')` by `.loc[lambda d: d['value'].eq('A')]` in the first code ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you unstack it, then you get a Series with a MultiIndex. You can then use a groupby and join the names corresponding to "A"-values:

```
def getAdmins(x):
    sel = x[x == "A"]
    return ",".join(sel.index.get_level_values(1)) if sel.any() else np.nan

df_new = df.unstack().groupby(level=0).agg(getAdmins)
```

Answer (score 0):

Should you need to be robust against empty string/NAs:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Joe Red', 'Joe Blue', 'Joe Green'],
    'Group 1': ['A', pd.NA, ''],
    'Group 2': ['', 'A', 'A'],
    'Group 3': ['', np.nan, 'A'],
})

df_t = df.set_index('Name').T.replace({
    'A': True,
    'U': False,
    '': False,
    pd.NA: False,
    np.nan: False,
})

df_t.apply(
    lambda x: df_t.columns[x].str.cat(sep=','), axis=1
).reset_index(name='Admins').rename(columns={'index': 'Groups'})
```

Output:

```
    Groups  Admins
0   Group 1 Joe Red
1   Group 2 Joe Blue,Joe Green
2   Group 3 Joe Green
```